# Conditional promise chaining?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a situation where depending upon a variable one of two situations can occur. Both of these situations return a promise and have the exact same logic applied afterwards.

I want something like this to happen:

```
userisBuyer ? Order.Create : Order.Create.As.Buyer
    .then //do same stuff for both
```

I realize this isn't valid logic but how could I accomplish something similar where I .then on both of those conditionally?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this in one line, as implied at by your question format:

```
(userisBuyer ? Order.Create() : Order.Create.As.Buyer()).then(function() {
     //do same stuff for both
});
```

---

But do you really want to?

```
var createMethod = userisBuyer ? Order.Create : Order.Create.As.Buyer;
createMethod().then(function() {

});
```

is much more readable in my eyes.

Comment: To each their own, I'm a fan of the readability of your first snippet (which also doesn't create an unnecessary variable).

Comment: @Adam Indeed - which is why I added it as a separate section, also almost added a comment about it straying into opinionated territory :)  I wouldn't worry too much about unncessary variables vs readability - if they are unnecessary, the optimiser will take care of them.

Answer (score 2):

```
let action = userisBuyer ? Order.Create : Order.Create.As.Buyer;

action()
.then(res => {your code})
```

This should do ?